# iOS App sometimes crashes on Release Mode (EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV))

Tags: ios, flutter, exception, mobile, exc-bad-access

Currently experiencing a problem where the app sometime crashes only in release mode. Any ideas on how to decode the IOS Crash log, i've attached a small section of the crash log below.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000004111401c
VM Region Info: 0x4111401c is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 3209592804
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 00000001005fc000-0000000100600000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...er.app/Runner

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [1113]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019c3c74ac object_isClass + 16 (objc-runtime-new.h:340)
1   Foundation                      0x000000019ca551a8 KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED + 44 (NSKeyValueObserving.m:1120)
2   Foundation                      0x000000019ca52cd0 NSKeyValueWillChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications + 272 (NSKeyValueObserving.m:1151)
3   AVFoundation                    0x00000001a6896348 -[AVPlayerItem _informObserversAboutAvailabilityOfTracks] + 56 (AVPlayerItem.m:3722)
4   AVFoundation                    0x00000001a6899374 -[AVPlayerItem _respondToBecomingReadyForBasicInspectionWithDuration:] + 296 (AVPlayerItem.m:4358)
5   AVFoundation                    0x00000001a68ae580 __avplayeritem_fpItemNotificationCallback_block_invoke + 2080 (AVPlayerItem.m:8874)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019c36b9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1408)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019c36c524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019c31e5b4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 904 (inline_internal.h:2484)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c624748 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1749)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c61f61c __CFRunLoopRun + 1724 (CFRunLoop.c:3069)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c61ec34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
12  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a676838c GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2246)
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a075122c UIApplicationMain + 1932 (UIApplication.m:4820)
14  Runner                          0x0000000100603380 main + 88 (main.m:7)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019c4a6800 start + 4

....

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000002809c1740   x1: 0x000000016f802310   x2: 0xfffffffffffffff0   x3: 0x000000016f802310
    x4: 0x0000000000000008   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x00000000000002d0
    x8: 0x0000000041114000   x9: 0x00000002809c2df0  x10: 0x00000002809cd4a0  x11: 0x00000002809cf780
   x12: 0x00000002809cd4a0  x13: 0x00000002809cf780  x14: 0x00000002809cfb40  x15: 0x00000002809ce4c0
   x16: 0x000000019c3ae8f0  x17: 0x000000019c58f928  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016f802310
   x20: 0x0000000000000008  x21: 0x00000002809c1740  x22: 0x000000028055e940  x23: 0x00000002807350c0
   x24: 0x0000000000000008  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000008  x27: 0x000000016f802310
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016f802300   lr: 0x000000019ca551a8
    sp: 0x000000016f8022e0   pc: 0x000000019c3c74ac cpsr: 0x20000000
   esr: 0x92000005 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault
```

Comment: I don't know flutter. If it behave same like native then you can follow [Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find out what was the issue?